Angular ngAfterContentChecked triggering non stop
I'm logging ngAfterContentChecked event and see this function triggering 10+ times per second. Is this normal? or when should this event be triggered? What could possibly cause this non stop retrigger?
Normally the UI frameworks only do change detection when there's a change in the data. How does Angular ngAfterContentChecked get triggered? Or generally when does Angular do the render / update checks?
Edit:
Could getter functions possibly be responsible for this? since they get evaluated and return a new value every time. But if they are only 'inputs' for children components, and they are not getting modified afterwards, they shouldn't cause the infinite triggers?

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a working stackblitz with the issue happening, steps for replication and expected result

I will just quote the Angular Docs:

The ngAfterContentChecked method runs every time the children nested
inside the component (its content) have been checked for changes.
This method runs very frequently and can significantly impact your
page's performance. Avoid defining this hook whenever possible, only
using it when you have no alternative.

So yeah, that is the normal behavior of that Lifecycle. It will be triggered whenever it detects any changes in the views(DOM) of its children.
If you want to trigger the same event only once after all the children nested inside the component (its content) have been initialized. You might want to use ngAfterContentInit
This will be triggered only once, so after it has been triggered, other changes wont trigger the same event again.
More about Angular Lifecycle Hooks
However if you are trying to check changes of data only, then I highly encourage you to learn more about signals and implement them.

Hi thanks for answering. But the def seems to conveniently evade the main question of WHEN the children get checked? Is this time based (unlike React etc)? or change based. What I want is to minimize these checks? Why would it check this much if there's no data change?

@TurtleTread It is based on whenever anything in the html changes, even a simple class change would fire this event. If the data doesn't change anything of the view, then it wont fire any events.
The reason why it does this, I can't really tell you :(. Could you give me a usage example on what you are trying to achieve? perhaps there is an alternative approach.
